# Conditionally choosing implementation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I have two implementations for a single interface and I segregated them using `@Qualifier("IMP1")` and `@Qualifier("IMP2")` and this is the case for most of the interfaces in my application.

And the requirement is autowire "IMP2" of an interface if available or autowire "IMP1".

As of now, I'm handling like

```
    @Autowired(required = false)
    @Qualifier("IMP1")
    HelloService imp1Service;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    @Qualifier("IMP2")
    HelloService imp2Service;


    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        if(l1Service != null){
            return imp2Service.getString();
        } else {
            return imp1Service.getString();
        }
    }
```

But this is not an elegant way as I've to check for all interfaces in the same way.
how to do this

Comment: Maybe [this](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/) helps

Comment: Would `@Profile` annotation help and then activate the relevant profiles?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on `IMP1Service`. In this case, `IMP1Service` will only be loaded in spring context when `IMP2Service` is missing. This will make sure that you have only implementation of `HelloService` interface in spring context i.e. either IMP1Service or IMP2Service

```java
@Service
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(IMP2Service.class)
class IMP1Service implements HelloService {
    // TODO
}
```

Since you have only one implementation of `HelloService`, you don't need to use `@Qualifier` annotation anymore

```java
    @Autowired(required = false)
    HelloService impService;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return impService.getString();
    }
```

You can read more about Conditional Annotations here:-
https://codingnconcepts.com/spring-boot/conditional-annotations-in-spring-boot/

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, but here the problem is IMP1 and IMP2 are coming from two different libraries
So we don't have IMP2 in the class path while coding IMP1

Comment: @BharateeshDiggavi This might not be fulfilling your use case but you can look at various `@Conditional` annotations available which might suffice your case. You can also write your custom conditions as well. Spring boot use `@Conditional` annotations a lot under the hood to make it opinionated.